# Get the closests id text from my tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table in my page

```
<tbody id="carga">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td id="nombre">esteban</td>
    <td id="apellido">aguirre</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td><a id="notas_carga" class="nota_1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td id="nombre">carolina</td>
    <td id="apellido">pozo</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td><a id="notas_carga" class="nota_2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td id="nombre">andres</td>
      <td id="apellido">garcia</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td><a id="notas_carga" class="nota_3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

All of this table was brought by a php script

And im my document im using Jquery

What i want to do is that when i click any of those `<a>` a script get me the closest values of those `#nombre` and `#apellido`

I been trying with .closest and it did not worked for me . Could you guide me with this ? .

Comment: share us what you have tried...

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique**

Comment: Can you show us how you tried to use `.closest()`.

Comment: $("body").on("click",".notas_1", function(){
   var nombre = $("a").closest("#nombre").text;
   var nombre = $("a").closest("#apellido").text;
   alert(nombre+apellido)
});

Comment: `.closest()` usually looks at the current element and its ancestor elements. The method that comes close to what you're doing is `.siblings()` but event that needs another helper method. See answers below.

Comment: @user2883338 first of all you are having same ids as you can see so that's wrong thing in your code  <a id="**notas_carga**" class="nota_1"> as well as **nombre** and
      **apellido** multipletimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest) to find the current `tr` then use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find) to find those two elements as below.

Just using `.closest()` won't work because it will search only the ancestor tree.

Also note that, the ID of the repeated elements are changed to class since ID of an element must be unique.

```js
$('#carga .notas_carga').click(function(e) {
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  e.preventDefault();
  var nombre = $tr.find('.nombre').text(),
    apellido = $tr.find('.apellido').text();
  $('#result').html(nombre + ':' + apellido)
})
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="carga">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="nombre">esteban</td>
      <td class="apellido">aguirre</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td><a class="nota_1 notas_carga"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="nombre">carolina</td>
      <td class="apellido">pozo</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td><a class="nota_2 notas_carga"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="nombre">andres</td>
      <td class="apellido">garcia</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td><a class="nota_3 notas_carga"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Just the code i was looking . Never  using same id's again . Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Element IDs should be unique within the entire document. So you may use class names instead of id as the selector. Use JQuery `closest` method. Refer [here](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$( "a" ).click(function(){
   var els = $(this).closest( ".nombre" ); //Returns closest elements with class name nombre
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @ArunPJohny has correctly stated, IDs should be unique and you should use classes instead.

You can then use `.parent()` -- of `a`, which is `td` -- and `.siblings()` to target the `td`s you're looking for.

```
$('#carga .notas_carga').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $td = $(this).parent();
    var nombre = $td.siblings('.nombre').text();
    var apellido = $td.siblings('.apellido').text();
    //your other code ...
});
```

Sample **corrected HTML**:

```
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td class="nombre">andres</td>
  <td class="apellido">garcia</td>
  <td>N/A</td>
  <td>N/A</td>
  <td>N/A</td>
  <td><a class="notas_carga nota_3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you can achieve using this way also

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#carga a').on('click',function(){       
        var $carga = $('#carga'),
         nombre = $(this).parents('tr').find('#nombre').text(),
            apellido = $(this).parents('tr').find('#apellido').text();
        
        $('.dispplay_result').append("<span>nombre == " + nombre + "\nAnd apellido == " +  apellido + "<\span>");
        console.log("nombre == " + nombre + "\nAnd apellido" +  apellido );      
    });
});
```

```css
span{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="carga">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td id="nombre">esteban</td>
    <td id="apellido">aguirre</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td><a id="notas_carga" class="nota_1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td id="nombre">carolina</td>
    <td id="apellido">pozo</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td><a id="notas_carga" class="nota_2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td id="nombre">andres</td>
      <td id="apellido">garcia</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td><a id="notas_carga" class="nota_3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div class="dispplay_result">
</div>
```

and here is the working demo of the above code you can check this

**[Check This](https://jsfiddle.net/ad7jgnuj/3/)**

Comment: @NEOJPK you can try this way also

Comment: Thank you ill check it out . Thank you for posting